# Entry and exit of Malaysia for multiple entry visa

Tags: multiple-entry, malaysia, visa-runs

I am a multiple entry visa holder for Malaysia for one year. I will be completing my first 30-day stay in two days. If I need to exit and re-enter Malaysia, how many days do I need to stay out of Malaysia to get another 30-day stay in Malaysia again?

Comment: I couldn't find a specific rule on this. Many countries apply the rule that you shouldn't be trying to live there by use of frequent visits. Thus, if you return after a couple of days away, just for a couple of days you're probably OK, but if you keep doing this, or if you return for a longer period you may be denied entry. The rule of thumb is generally, stay away for as long as you have been in the country.

Comment: Please note that the marked duplicate is for someone who wants to do repeated visits on a "visa on arrival". The circumstances for a 1-year multiple entry visa may be different.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you are doing in Malaysia If you are studying or working. You will need to get a study permit letter from your school or employer about your absent, while you are away for a long time.